# Read the content of an email sent over via SMTP?

Tags: email, smtp

I am currently setting an email server that sends out an email using smtp, I've used [smtpfaker](http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/) to check whether the mail is actually being sent, but cannot see the content of the mail using that application is it somehow possible to read, just to be sure that the content is correct.